# Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause. Error in Maria DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB IMDB movie dataset and I was trying to solve the below question. Movies table contains id,name,rank and year column

```
A decade is a sequence of 10 consecutive years. For example, say in your database you have movie information starting from 1965. Then the first decade is 1965, 1966, ..., 1974; the second one is 1967, 1968, ..., 1976 and so on. Find the decade D with the largest number of films and the total number of films in D.
```

I am getting the below error when i tried to execute the below query

`SELECT
  SUM(T3.MOVIE_PER_YEAR),
  T3.GROUP_PER_DECADE
  FROM
  (
SELECT
      CEIL(T2.ROW_NUM/10) AS GROUP_PER_DECADE,
      T2.MOVIE_PER_YEAR,
      T2.YEAR
FROM
      (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.YEAR ASC) AS row_num,
            T1.MOVIE_PER_YEAR,
            T1.YEAR
        FROM
            (SELECT 
              COUNT(M.id) AS MOVIE_PER_YEAR
              ,M.year 
            FROM 
              movies M 
            GROUP BY 
              M.year
            )T1
    )T2
)T3 GROUP BY GROUP_PER_DECADE;`

Error:-

```
Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Same type of query is working in Oracle DB.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdf8e3/9

Please help me on this.

Comment: I actually don't see a grouping problem with your query.  Are you certain that the above query is verbatim what you are running on MariaDB?

Comment: MariaDB 10.1 doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: MariaDB support row_number() function.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/

Comment: **"MariaDB starting with 10.2"** Your question is tagged `mariadb-10.1` if that is not correct please edit the tags.

Comment: Not Sure Sir. I am just practicing some machine learning on this database. Unfortunately this data set is only available on maria Db.https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/dataset/IMDb. @Tim

Comment: With the addition of table aliases, the same query works fine on [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdf8e3/12) and [MariaDB 10.2+](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1bdc2fd762a5ea9863d71f79e253a8df)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.If you see my inner most query, there I am using one group by function for counting each year movie. After that I am trying to group the movie count by there decade. If you see the table structure, the table contains id,name,year and rank. Probably for two group by clause i am getting this error. I am not sure. https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/dataset/IMDb

Answer (score 0):

Can't the task be done more simply:

```
SELECT FLOOR(year / 10) * 10 AS decade,
       COUNT(*) AS movies_per_decade
    FROM Movies
```

That assumes that, for example, all of 1980-1989 is the "1980 decade".

If you want "decades ago", then change to something like `FLOOR(YEAR(NOW() - year) / 10) AS decades_ago`.

(This will work on any version of MySQL/MariaDB.)